# How do i get from a website a class element value?

Tags: c#, html, .net, winforms

I have this element

```
<span class="validationMsg">
    <span id="TapuzLogin1_ctl01_UserNameRequired" title="יש להקליד שם משתמש" style="color:Red;display:none;">* יש להקליד שם משתמש<br>
    </span>
    <span id="TapuzLogin1_ctl01_PasswordRequired" title="יש להקליד סיסמה" style="color:Red;display:none;">* יש להקליד סיסמה<br>
    </span>שם המשתמש או הסיסמה אינם נכונים
</span>
```

The class is "validationMsg"
And the value i need to get the string is on the bottom:

שם המשתמש או הסיסמה אינם נכונים

This is in hebrew.

I can get and use by Id

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   navigate("mysite.net");
   webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("UserName").InnerText = textBox1.Text.ToString();
   webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("Password").InnerText = textBox2.Text.ToString();
   webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("LoginButton").InvokeMember("click");
}
```

But how do i get the class element value this string in hebrew indicate if i logged in fine or not.
And i want to check that if this element contain this string then the login was wrong.

This is my complete code in form1 of how i log in.
And if i put the right user name and password i can log in fine.
But how can i indicate if the put wrong password or username ?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using mshtml;
using HtmlAgilityPack;

namespace WebSite_Login_And_Browsing
{
    public partial class LogIn : Form
    {
        IHTMLDocument2 doc;
        string pagecontent;

        public LogIn()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            webBrowser1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
        }

        public void ihtml(HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument dom)
        {
            try
            {
                pagecontent = "";
                doc = webBrowser1.Document.DomDocument as IHTMLDocument2;
                pagecontent = doc.body.innerHTML;
                dom.LoadHtml(pagecontent);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                dom.LoadHtml(webBrowser1.DocumentText.ToString());
            }

        }

        public void navigate(string url)
        {
            webBrowser1.Navigate(url);
            while (webBrowser1.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
            {
                Application.DoEvents();
            }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            navigate("http://www.tapuz.co.il/Common/SignInPage.aspx?backUrl=http://www.tapuz.co.il/Common/SignIn.aspx@loginDone=1");

            webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("UserName").InnerText = textBox1.Text.ToString();       webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("Password").InnerText = textBox2.Text.ToString();          webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("LoginButton").InvokeMember("click");
        }
    }
}
```

My code in button1 click button event

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
navigate("http://www.tapuz.co.il/Common/SignInPage.aspx?backUrl=http://www.tapuz.co.il/Common/SignIn.aspx@loginDone=1");         webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("TapuzLogin1_ctl01_UserName").InnerText = textBox1.Text.ToString();         webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("TapuzLogin1_ctl01_Password").InnerText = textBox2.Text.ToString();       webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("TapuzLogin1_ctl01_LoginButton").InvokeMember("click");
            }
```

Document completed event

```
void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            var items = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("span");
            foreach (HtmlElement item in items)
            {
                if (item.GetAttribute("className") == "validationMsg")
                {
                    logingResults = item.InnerText;
                    if (logingResults.Contains("שם המשתמש או הסיסמה אינם נכונים"))
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: `Document.GetElementsByTagName`, loop over the returned array looking for the one that has the className you are interested in.

Comment: If I want to extract a single question form this post what's the question? it this your question: **I want to click on login button in the given [page](http://www.tapuz.co.il/Common/SignInPage.aspx?backUrl=http://www.tapuz.co.il/Common/SignIn.aspx@loginDone=1) and check if there is `</span>שם המשתמש או הסיסמה אינם נכונים</span>` in result page?**

Comment: What is  "public void ihtml(HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument dom)" for?

Comment: The given web site has 404 problem or another problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using mshtml;
using HtmlAgilityPack;

namespace WebSite_Login_And_Browsing
{
    public partial class LogIn : Form
    {
        public LogIn()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            webBrowser1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += process1;
            webBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.tapuz.co.il/Common/SignInPage.aspx?backUrl=http://www.tapuz.co.il/Common/SignIn.aspx@loginDone=1");
        }

        private void process1(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs args)
        {
            webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted -= process1;
            webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += process2;

            try
            {
                webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("UserName").InnerText = textBox1.Text.ToString();
                webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("Password").InnerText = textBox2.Text.ToString();
                webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("LoginButton").InvokeMember("click");
            }
            catch
            {
                webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted -= process2;
            }
        }

        private void process2(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs args)
        {
            webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted -= process2;

            var items = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("span");
            foreach (HtmlElement item in items)
            {
                if (item.GetAttribute("className") == "validationMsg")
                {
                    if (item.InnerText.Contains("שם המשתמש או הסיסמה אינם נכונים"))
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("State 1");
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }

            MessageBox.Show("State 2");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This code is working in my machine. I don't know why are you getting error.

Comment: Levent there was a mistake by me that i fixed i typed the first GetElementByID by mistake instead UserName it was UserNamm but now after fixed it when it's getting to process2 event it's doing only one itertion in the foreach when it's getting inside to the second IF: if (item.InnerText.Contains and hterefore it's getting only the first result of the validationMsg and not the other results. Any ideas why it's making one itertion there ?

Comment: I mean it's doing 4 loops in the foreach 4 itertions but getting inside to the if (item.InnerText.Contains only once.  It's getting inside after this line only once: if (item.GetAttribute("className") == "validationMsg")

Comment: I also extended this IF check: if (item.InnerText.Contains("שם המשתמש או הסיסמה אינם נכונים") || item.InnerText.Contains("קיימת חריגה במספר נסיונות הכניסה")) since now i'm getting the second string: "קיימת חריגה במספר נסיונות הכניסה" but i can't get to it. Maybe it's not in the same validationMsg className ? The second string i'm getting is a warning i tried to log in too many times.

Comment: I checked now again the second string קיימת חריגה במספר נסיונות הכניסה is in the same className validationMsg but the foreach loop not get there it's getting to the if contains only once the other 3 loops not getting there at all.

Comment: Now it's only show when i log in with wrong details this: "שם המשתמש או הסיסמה אינם נכונים" but the foreach loop in process2 event never get to it. I see in items 4 items but it's getting inside and check if contains only once.

Comment: Just remove the break (or return) line from the loop

Comment: Iteration stops when it see a break or return keyword

Comment: Did it work for you on my website ? Try navigatin to this: "http://www.tapuz.co.il/Common/SignInPage.aspx?backUrl=http://www.tapuz.co.il/Common/SignIn.aspx@loginDone=1" and then instead UserName Password and LoginButton put: TapuzLogin1_ctl01_UserName and TapuzLogin1_ctl01_Password and TapuzLogin1_ctl01_LoginButton

Comment: It's not the break or return since it's not getting there at all. It's getting to this line only once: if (item.InnerText.Contains("שם המשתמש או הסיסמה אינם נכונים") || item.InnerText.Contains("קיימת חריגה במספר נסיונות הכניסה")) and i checked in the variable items there 4 items and in none of them i found "שם המשתמש או הסיסמה אינם נכונים" or "קיימת חריגה במספר נסיונות הכניסה" not sure why. I know they are in the className validationMsg but i didn't see it in the items and the foreach loop never get to the break or return at all.

Comment: The page refreshes rapidly and url is 404.asp. The web site has a problem.

Comment: Strange i can navigate to it no problems. Try this: http://www.tapuz.co.il/Common/SignInPage.aspx without the other part.

Comment: I must quit Dainel, sorry, that's enough for now.

Answer (score 1):

```
var items = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("span");
foreach (HtmlElement item in items)
{
    if (item.GetAttribute("className") == "validationMsg")
    {
        // Now you can check the item's value by comparing item.InnerText
    }
}
```

Comment: Levent inside the loop it's getting to the InnerText of "* יש להקליד שם משתמש\r\n* יש להקליד סיסמה" but it's not continue after it and not getting to the </span>שם המשתמש או הסיסמה אינם נכונים</span> i used a breakpoint. I edited you answer in my code just inside the button1 click event after the last GetElementById line. Inside the loop in your answer i did: string result = item.InnerText; but after the first itertion it's not continue to the next one.

Comment: Can you post your code inside the button1 click event handler?

Comment: Well, that's an important issue. You should always wait for webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted event for an operation on the Document object.

Comment: I am not sure but using item.InnerHtml instead of item.InnerText can solve   the <span> issue

Comment: Added my DocumentCompleted event code to the question. Is that fine to do it this way ?

Comment: while (webBrowser1.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
{
    Application.DoEvents();
}

This code is dangerous and should be avoided. Event handling is not done by this way.

Comment: I removed that while part now i'm getting exception null on the first  webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById line in the button click event. Document is null. What should i do and how in the navigate method instead the while ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are will like to use javascript to get the text.Hope this snippet will help you

```
document.getElementsByClassName('validationMsg')[0].innerText
```

[WORKING DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/bz2ng1g5/)

Apologize if I have missed any point